# Return back redirects me to home page in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5

So what I'm trying to do is to redirect the user to his previous location whenever a 404 error appears. That means, I want to simply not allow him to reach unexisting http addresses and to return him back instead. I did as follows in the App/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($this->isHttpException($exception))
    {
        switch ($exception->getStatusCode()) 
        {
            // not found
            case '404':
            return back();
            break;

            default:
                return parent::render($request, $exception);
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

The problem - I'm getting redirected to my home page each time. What could cause it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried with `return redirect()->back()` instead of `return back()`

Comment: @carrion Yes, same result

Comment: It probably has something to do with your laravel installation, redirecting to normal urls/actions work?

Comment: I didn't quite get your point. I've done nothing additional regarding redirects, could you suggest any particular occurance, that could cause that? The only thing I've used is the 'return redirect('some/url');' in controllers in certain scenarios (on actions).

Comment: can you try and echo `URL::previous();` or `$request->header('referer');` to check the page that sent the request

Comment: It is correct indeed, the right url appears. I guess the problem is with the `back()` helper or? Because if I use one of your suggestion with the redirect function, I'm getting right back! So it's working, but I'm still wondering what causes the other problem.

Comment: Something interesting. That's my example url: `http://localhost:8000/configurate/element-156`
If I imput wrongly something after the dash, where I have a custom middleware to `abort(404)` on invalid element ID, I get the right back url. But if I misspell the keyword registered in the `web.api` file and write for example `elkement` instead of `element`, then it redirects me home, still registerting a 404 error, the `URL::previous()` value is just the home directory... Pretty strange.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @Mav Sorry I'm so late to respond, it's been quite some time... But as far as I recall the problem was that I had another url registered to listen for a parameter after the dash, so the misspelled url was actually getting accepted as a param to another action and the magic happened there. Could be really misleading!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. I fixed it by removing the following meta tag in the head section.

```html
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```